# Unable to reproduce paper results (sample size)

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, sample-size

I am interested in using the results from [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2146/abstract) (*Modified exact sample size for a binomial proportion with special emphasis on diagnostic rest parameter estimation* by Geoffrey Fosgate) to calculate sample sizes. There is an implementation of the algorithm used to calculate the sample size in R's binomSamSize package. I have checked the code used to calculate this and it seems to follow the paper exactly, but the results shown in the paper's results section do not seem to be reproducible. The sample sizes turn out to be too small.

The paper requires a subscription to be viewed in it's entirety, but here is a snippet to show how the sample size is calculated:

[image]

Here are the results I want to reproduce: 
[image]

Here is the code I am using (lifted from the binomSamSize package):

```
ciss.midp <- function(p0, d, alpha, nMax = 1e+06){
  pi.L <- p0 - d
  pi.U <- p0 + d
  if (pi.L < 0) 
    stop("p0 - d is below zero!")
  if (pi.U > 1) 
    stop("p0 + d is above one!")
  n <- floor(max(1/p0, 1/(1 - p0)))
  done <- FALSE
  while (!done & (n < nMax)) {
    n <- n + 1
    x <- round(p0 * n)
    lhs2 <- 1/2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.L) + 1/2 * 
      dbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.U) + 
      pbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.L, lower.tail = FALSE) + 
      pbinom(x - 1, size = n, prob = pi.U)
    if (!is.na(lhs2)) {
      done <- (lhs2 < alpha)
    }
  }
  return(n)
}
```

What I end up getting to produce the circled column is this:

```
> sapply(seq(0.5, 0.9, 0.05), function(i) ciss.midp(p0=i, d=0.1, alpha=0.1))
[1] 68 67 65 61 57 50 42 34 23
```

PS: If there is anything else I can provide to make this easier to answer, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Posting relevant portions of papers is considered fair use almost everywhere (although I am told that laws vary from country to country).  It would be unlikely to raise objections here.  Posting the entirety of a paper would be frowned on.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the quick response. I added the relevant snippet.

Comment: Nothings seems to be off.  You best bet is to contact the authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the author's
implementation -  despite the description - starts with a large n and
works back and stops at the first time we are above alpha, thus
returning the last n where the sum was below alpha? At least an
implementation of such an algo would be consistent with the results of the paper
(test code below).

There appear to be more than one n, where a switch from the sum being
above alpha for n and being below alpha for n+1... However, I do think
it's better to go from small n and up.

```
##Go the other way...not my 1st choice though...
ciss.midp2 <- function (p0, d, alpha, nMax = 1e+05) {
    pi.L <- p0 - d
    pi.U <- p0 + d
    if (pi.L < 0)
        stop("p0 - d is below zero!")
    if (pi.U > 1)
        stop("p0 + d is above one!")
    n <- nMax
    done <- FALSE
    while (!done & (n > 0)) {
        n <- n - 1
        x <- round(p0 * n)
        lhs2 <- 1/2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.L) +
          pbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.L, lower.tail = FALSE) +
          (1 - pbinom(x-1, size = n, prob = pi.U, lower.tail=FALSE)) +
          1/2*dbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.U)

        if (!is.na(lhs2)) {
            done <- (lhs2 > alpha)
        }
    }
    return(n+1)
}

library("binomSamSize")
p.grid <- seq(0.5, 0.9, 0.05)
sapply(p.grid, function(i) ciss.midp(p0=i, d=0.1, alpha=0.1))
[1] 68 67 65 61 57 50 42 34 23
sapply(p.grid, function(i) ciss.midp2(p0=i, d=0.1, alpha=0.1)
[1] 68 67 65 61 57 52 45 39 29
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This makes sense, but when I try to replicate another result in the same table, I don't get the same results again. To replicate the 99% confidence level at 0.05 margin of error, `sapply(seq(0.5, 0.9, 0.05), function(i) ciss.midp2(i, 0.05, 0.01))` gives `662 654 635 603 560 503 434 358 268` instead of the author's result `662 655 635 605 560 500 430 353 260`

Comment: Maybe part of the problem is the numerical precision of the different implementations (R vs. Fortran)? Still, in R I'd go for the R ciss.midp function, for example: 
> p0 <- 0.85 ; d <- 0.05 ; x <- round(p0*n) ; alpha <- 0.01 
> (n <- ciss.midp(p0=p0, d=d, alpha=alpha))
[1] 342
> 1/2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.L) + 1/2 *
+             dbinom(x, size = n, prob = pi.U) + pbinom(x, size = n,
+             prob = pi.L, lower.tail = FALSE) + pbinom(x - 1,
+             size = n, prob = pi.U)
[1] 0.009965654
Maybe try to get the Fortran code from the author?

Comment: I got the author's Fortran code. It is largely posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619962/converting-a-fortran-program-to-a-subroutine-to-be-called-from-r